# I want to get FrameStyle to consider the entire Directive

Tags: frame

I am using Mathematica 10.3 on an old Mac (macOS Mojave 10.14.6) if this is relevant to my question.

I have the problem that whenever I use FrameStyle in a Framed environment, only color commands get accepted. Commands like Thick or Dashed or Dotted get completely ignored.

For example:

```
panelLabel2[x_] := 
  Framed[Panel[x, FrameMargins -> 0], 
   Background -> Lighter[Gray, 0.5], 
   FrameStyle -> Directive[Black, Thick, Dashed], 
   RoundingRadius -> 10];

Graph[{{1, 2, 3} <-> {1, 2, 4}, {1, 2, 3} <-> {1, 2, 5}, {1, 2, 
    4} <-> {1, 2, 5}}, 
 VertexLabels -> {{1, 2, 3} -> 
    Placed[ToString[{1, 2, 3}], Center, panelLabel2], {1, 2, 4} -> 
    Placed[ToString[{1, 2, 4}], Center, panelLabel2], {1, 2, 5} -> 
    Placed[ToString[{1, 2, 5}], Center, panelLabel2]}]
```

Moreover, I'd like to know how to get rid of the very pale but visible tiny "inner frame" displayed in the vertices, i.e. I'd like the entire frame filled with the light background color, not only the background of the vertex labels.

Thanks a lot already for all your help!

[image]

Comment: On v12.2 on Win7-x64, `panelLabel2[x_] := Framed[
   Panel[x, FrameMargins -> 2
    , Background -> Lighter[Gray, 0.5]]
   , Background -> Lighter[Gray, 0.5]
   , FrameStyle -> Directive[
     Black, Thick, Dashed]
   , RoundingRadius -> 10
   ];` gives this [output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dx40X.png). I have added a `Background` for the panel as well. It seems this is version related.

Comment: Version 10.4 on Windows 11 also gives the correct output, but Version 9.0 fails almost as you show in the question (the background color works, contrary to your screenshot). As for the inner frame: That is caused by `Panel`, simply remove it if you don't want it. You can also try `Pane` instead if you need something with the `FrameMargins` option. Finally, I am unfortunately not sure how much help you will receive here for such an old version of Mathematica